# How to download Facebook archive completely?

Tags: facebook, download, facebook-archive

My account got blocked, and I'm trying to download my data.

The problem is my network, it's 12Mb/s, Facebook logs me out automatically after about 30-40 minutes, and the download stops. The download time is 2 hours.

I have tried using download managers instead of browser's own, but they can't resume downloading the .zip file, so it's impossible to get the full file, only the first ~2GB of it.

How can I download the archive completely? Is there any way to prevent Facebook from logging me out automatically?